# Google Data Studio - How to embed a dashboard that the user can only see the embedded dashboard and not go to the Data Studio page?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dashboard, looker-studio, data-studio-custom-visuals

Is there a way to remove the bottom Data Studio pop-up of my embedded dashboard?

[image]

The reason is that I want to embed a dashboard on my website, but I don't want to the user be able to go to the dashboard on Data Studio and be able to copy the link and send it over to other people for security issues.

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (as well as a link to the respective embedded Google Data Studio Report) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this without violating Google Terms of services. As you can see [here](https://policies.google.com/terms#:%7E:text=Google%20content,Brand%20Permissions%20page.).

If you use some script in your page to hide this elements, its considered violating terms of services and it may be identified and they can remove your content, deactivate your account and  among other actions.

In summary, its better not. And there are useful links on the footer, as the buttons to change report pages.